# Select a row from rows with similar data

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I hope someone will be able to solve my issue with `knex.js`

There is a table-"task_history" and it has following columns:
`id`, `task_id`, `duration`, `date`, `start_time`, `finish_time`

Let's say I have three rows inside task_history table:

```
row 1 - id(1) task_id(3333), duration(200), date(20171204)
        ,start_time("2017-10-19 21:00:00+11"), finish_time("2017-12-05 00:59:18.943+11")

row 2 - id(2) task_id(3333),  duration(200), date(20171204)
        ,start_time("2017-10-19 21:00:00+11"), finish_time()

row 3 - id(3) task_id(4444), duration(100), date(20171204)
        ,start_time("2017-10-19 21:00:00+11"), finish_time()
```

As you can see, row 1 and row 2 are almost same except id, finish_time. 
row 2 has "null" value for the finish_time column.

When I try the following query it returns me the row2 and row3.

```
select * from task_history where date=20171204 and finish_time is null
```

But, that's not what I want. I don't want to get any row if its `task_id` exists in another row, but also it has value for the `finish_time` column.

The query should return row 3 only. 
But row 1 and 2, because row 1 has `finish_time` value and the same `task_id` with the row2.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try `DISTINCT ON`?..

```
select  distinct on (task_id) * from task_history 
where date=20171204 
order by tastk_id, finish_time  nulls last;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and get back to you soon.

Comment: The query does work kinda opposite way I wanted, I could get the right result with nulls first instead of nulls last.
Btw, Do you happen to know how to run that query on knex.js?

Comment: sorry - I don't know knex

Answer (score 1):

> But, that's not what I want. I don't want to get any row if its
>   task_id exists in another row, but also it has value for the
>   finish_time column.

I understand this like

> Select all `task` rows  exluding rows with
>   `task_id` that exists in a row that has `finished != null`

This would be `SQL`ized like

```
SELECT * FROM task t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT id FROM task -- note the 'id' is not important here, could be '*' also
   WHERE task_id=t.task_id AND finish_time IS NOT NULL
);
```